# How to re install podfile.lock in a flutter application

Tags: flutter

My Xcode build was taking so long to run after I tried using firebase. I found a solution that required me to add this to my podfile

```
pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '6.26.0'
```

and then delete the podfile.lock to finally run pod install. But the pod install is bringing this error since

```
[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.
```

I have tried installing cocoa pods again but still the pod install command did not work nether the pod init one

What can I do to solve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you must navigate to the `ios` directory

```
cd ios
```

Then run any command related to the iOS build, in your case try

```
flutter clean
rm -Rf ios/Pods
rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

Comment: Below is the error I now receive

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseFirestore":
  In Podfile:
    FirebaseFirestore (from `https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git`, tag `6.26.0`)

    cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`) was resolved to 2.5.4, which depends on
      Firebase/Firestore (= 8.8.0) was resolved to 8.8.0, which depends on
        FirebaseFirestore (~> 8.8.0)

Comment: You don't need to add the FirebaseFirestore pod into your podfile
The (Firestore) package did it for you